# Allow pointer or value as argument in method

Tags: go, generics

I would like to be able to restrict the type tied to `Auth` while allowing for either a pointer or value to be passed as an argument, namely val, for the `Marshal` method. The Unmarshal requires a pointer, but the Marshal can be either a pointer or value without affecting functionality (all unnecessary code was removed). Is this possible?

```
type Auth[A any] struct {
    // ...
}

func (a *Auth[A]) Unmarshal(b []byte, val *A) error {
    // ...
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, val); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func (a *Auth[A]) Marshal(val *A) ([]byte, error) {
    b, err := json.Marshal(src)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // ...
    return b, nil
}
```

Reasoning why I would like to be able to do this: I would like to be able to call `Marshal` with a basic type, eg. a string, without having to get a pointer to it.

What I would like to be able to do:

```
a := &Auth{}
a.Marshal("val")
```

Current implementation:

```
a := &Auth{}
s := "val"
a.Marshal(&s)
```

Comments:
Using `Marshal(val A)` will not work.
Eg.

```
a := Auth[string]
a.Marshal("val") // works, but only if Unmarshal uses *A

type temp struct {}
b := Auth[*temp]
b.Marshal(&temp{})
out := new(temp)
b.Unmarshal(data, &out) // this is the issue that I first presented, but now in the unmarshal
```

Comment: Why not declare `Marshal(val A)`?

Comment: @BurakSerdar  `Marshal(val A)` won't allow for calling with a pointer then.

Comment: Indeed, as @BurakSerdar suggests, since `A` is already any, using `val A` means you could use anything, pointer or not. Note that your `Unmarshal` is the more problematic case because it lends itself to pointer-to-pointer, e.g. a `Auth[*string]` would require `Unmarshal` to receive a `**string`.

Comment: @Adrian No, when you declare, Auth[string] or Auth[*string], then you can only use whatever val specifies in both methods. Eg. Auth[string] can only be a string, unless I state that val takes *A. And, there's no reason to use Auth[*string], that would just likely be an improper use of the api, which is out of my control; I can document this behavior, but otherwise it's up to the end user to implement this correctly.

Comment: I guess the question is: why would you want to call Marshal with a pointer?

Comment: @BurakSerdar It really isn't and I already went out of my way in the question to explain the reasoning behind this. But, if you have a pointer that you don't want to have to deference every time you call the function. Allowing for either would keep the api consistent with most marshallers.

Comment: The reasoning is not clear for many who are used to seeing marshallers taking value args instead of pointers. You can simply dereference the value. If you want to pass both pointers and values, use `any`. There is no mechanism in the language that will let you specify `pass a value of type T, pointer or not`. Semantics and mechanics of the two are very different.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I sincerely hope you don't think that an empty interface is a value type, which is what the majority of popular marshallers and unmarshallers use: https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal, https://github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack/blob/v5/encode.go#L60, https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/blob/v3/yaml.go#L218. As for "you can simply dereference the value" is not a solution, when the original problem was how do I avoid getting a reference for basic types. And, you're wrong again about there not being a mechanism, Auth[A any, B A | *A]. It's embarassing people upvoted you.

Comment: An empty interface is a type. It can contain a value, or a pointer. You don't need to get a reference for a value type if the marshaler does not require a pointer. Maybe you should explain why you want to do this?

Comment: @BurakSerdar Yes, it is a type, but that's not what I said; I said a value type, mind you all types are value types, but I said this with reference to your comment regarding "value args". However, interfaces are references. Saying, "It can contain a value, or a pointer", is meaningless as a pointer can do the same, and by your logic a pointer is a value type. As for, "Maybe you should explain why you want to do this", try reading the question; I put a specific section when I made it that starts with "Reasoning why I would like to be able to do this".

Comment: An `any` argument can contain a `*int`, or an `int`.So "It can contain a value or a pointer" is not meaningless. A pointer cannot do the same. If you want to call `Marshal` without a pointer, then declare it without a pointer, i.e. `Marshal(val A)`. Or, declare it with `any`, and as long as the underlying implementation is `json.Marshal`, you can pass a `string` or a `*string`.

Comment: A pointer can contain another pointer or a value; I'm not sure how you don't understand that. And, you keep missing that the `A`, which is constrained to `any`, is tied to `Auth`. That means that if `Auth` is instantiated with `*int`, then I can only pass in an `*int`. As well, that if I declare `Marshal`'s `val` as `any` it loses the type constraint which is the whole point of using generics for this. Unlike json, the `Marshal` and `Unmarshal` are constrained by `A` to provide type safety.

Comment: So your concern is type safety. That is not what the question is asking. In that case, your verdict below is correct, you cannot do this. You are too eager to discuss what I don't know or don't understand, which is not really helpful for you. What you are asking can be understood in many ways. In all this thread, this is the first time you talked about type safety.

Comment: Type safety the core reason to use generics, otherwise you would just use an empty interface. Nothing that you said was helpful to me; especially when you incorrectly told me that, "[t]here is no mechanism in the language that will let you specify pass a value of type T, pointer or not".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve you need to make 2 small changes:

1. operate on an `A` value, not `*A`
2. ***return*** a new `A` from `Unmarshal()` rather than accepting a `*A` arg

i.e.:

```golang
type Auth[A any] struct{}

func (a *Auth[A]) Unmarshal(b []byte) (A, error) {
    result := new(A)
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, result)
    return *result, err
}

func (a *Auth[A]) Marshal(val A) ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(val)
}
```

In use, using a `string` type argument and a `*Foo` type argument (where `Foo` is a struct type) (error handling omitted for clarity):

```golang
type Foo struct {
    S string
}

func main() {
    va := Auth[string]{}
    pa := Auth[*Foo]{}

    // Marshal a value type and a pointer to a Foo
    mv, _ := va.Marshal("string")
    mp, _ := pa.Marshal(&Foo{"bar"})

    // Emit the marshalled []bytes
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", mv)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", mp)

    // Unmarshal from the marshalled []byte for
    // both the value and the pointer
    v, _ := va.Unmarshal(mv)
    p, _ := pa.Unmarshal(mp)

    // Emit the unmarshalled results and their type
    fmt.Printf("%s %[1]T\n", v)
    fmt.Printf("%s %[1]T\n", p)
}
```

Comment: I attempted the adaptations, but this still wasn't the fix I was aiming for. I think the one thing I was missing from my question was that I wanted to be able to pass in a value or pointer to some type A for the marshal function, but on the same instance of Auth. Meaning that if I created Auth[string], I could call Marshal with either a string or *string. I believe that generic methods were what I was after, eg `(a *Auth[A]) Marshal[B A | *A](val B)`, but aren't currently viable. Thank you though!

Comment: `string` and `*string` are different type; a generic function can't help you with that since each type parameter is still of only one, fixed type when instantiated.  The only way I can think for you to get what you want is to use a non-generic `Marshal` function accepting an `any` argument and using reflection to vary the function behaviour according to the actual type of the value passed.  Which, for the record: Yuck. :)